# How to manage the Notification under the upper "Notification" area inside our sharepoint online classic team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, modern-pages, notifications

I am not sure how we can manage the notifications which are shown under the Notification area inside our sharepoint online classic team site collection:-

[image]

For example we have our "Site Pages" library linked to managed metadata column (named "Category"). so when users add new modern pages they can link them with the managed metadata column, as follow:-

[image]

we got a request from our customer, asking that when a News modern page is created, and this modern News page is linked to a specific term inside the "Category" property, to show this action inside the Notifications section. so can anyone advice on this please? is there a way to define when notifications should be shown for users?

Of course i am not talking about users' alerts, i am referring to the Notification section as shown in the above picture.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notifications Suite Bar：

Previously, you and your users would receive notifications only within the service you were using. For example, you would receive new mail messages only when you were using the Outlook Web App and not when you were working in SharePoint Online. You now receive notifications for new mail, reminders, and system alerts in all your Office 365 services. (Notice the triangle shaped alert icon with the number 1 below it on the blue bar above)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but can you explain it in more details please? and which ` (Notice the triangle shaped alert icon with the number 1 below it on the blue bar above)` you are referring to ?